# Which column can be used to uniquely identify a row in the Application Insights traces table?

Tags: azure-application-insights

Does the `traces` table in Application Insights have a column that uniquely identifies each row in the table, like a primary key?

The only schema documentation I could find, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/traces, suggests the `itemId` column is a unique identifier:

> Unique ID of the telemetry item assigned by the Application Insights ingestion endpoint.

This sounded promising but I wasn't sure if a telemetry item assigned by the ingestion endpoint is the equivalent of a row in the table.

Looking at our production logs in Application Insights I found 72 `itemId`s recorded more than once in the last 24 hours. So either there is a bug in Application Insights or the `itemId` doesn't uniquely identify a row in the `traces` table.

Would any other column, or combination of columns, work to uniquely identify each row in the table?

Comment: May I also what your use case is?

Comment: @PeterBons: We've got some JSON in the message column. It represents a hierarchy (group - container - item). We shred the JSON to display the group, container and item as columns, then filter on those columns. We want to include some other columns in the final results, such as various customDimensions. I wanted to avoid including the additional columns while we're manipulating the JSON, since we start off with a lot of data and filter out most of it.  So I wanted to add the additional columns after the filtering. I thought joining via a row identifier, if one exists, would be simple.

Comment: Did you investigate the traces sharing the same itemId? I have some as well but it seems the data is ingested twice as all the fields are the same (itemId, operationId, timestamp , message etc)...  I confirmed that using this query `traces
| summarize count() by itemId, operation_Id, tostring(customDimensions), message, timestamp
| order by count_ desc`. Could be an AI issue.

Comment: @PeterBons:  Yes, I found the same thing.  I tried a `distinct` and found the duplicate rows disappeared, so at least all the columns I was interested in were identical.  Even the `timestamp` values were identical to the millisecond.  So I suspect it's an issue with AI.